# Clojure Update Atom PersistentQueue

Tags: clojure

I am trying to maintain a queue of orders and "cook" them using the FIFO process. Using the atom I am able to update the queue but the last two line are not working. What I need is to remove the first element and update the atom(queue) with the remaining list.

Thanks,
R.

```
(ns example.atomqueue
  (:use clojure.pprint))

(def orders-queue (atom clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY))

(defrecord Order [fplate splate])

(defn add-order [order]
  (swap! orders-queue conj order))

(add-order (->Order "Soup" "Fish&Chips"))
(pprint orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Salad" "Hamburger"))
(pprint orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Rice" "Steak"))
(pprint orders-queue)

;;NOT SURE IF CORRECT
(defn cook-order [orders]
  (swap! orders-queue (pop orders)))

;;EXCEPTION
(cook-order orders-queue)
```

Comment: what you need is probably `(defn cook-order [] (swap! orders-queue pop))`

Comment: Yes, you are wright. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. leetwinski this is the right solution:

```
(ns chaptertwo.atom
  (:use clojure.pprint))

(def orders-queue (atom clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY))

(defrecord Order [fplate splate])

(defn add-order [order]
  (swap! orders-queue conj order))

(defn cook-order [] (swap! orders-queue pop))

(add-order (->Order "Soup" "Fish&Chips"))
(pprint orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Salad" "Hamburger"))
(pprint orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Rice" "Steak"))
(pprint orders-queue)

(cook-order )
(pprint orders-queue)
```